# Jersey message body reader not found in maven-built JAR

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, executable-jar, maven-assembly-plugin

My application uses a REST (JAX-RS Jersey) interface. When I run it in Eclipse, everything'
s fine. The domain objects are annotated, I'm not using XML files for the REST mapping.

Now I created a standalone JAR using the maven-assembly-plugin, which packs the application and all dependencies in a single, executable JAR file. This also seems to work.

But when I start the application and request an object from the server, Jersey complains, that it can't find a message body reader:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java type, class de.rybu.atuin.core.entity.User, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
```

Any ideas why this happens?

**EDIT:** After I slept a night over it, I noticed that it complains about JSON... but I'm using only XML for serialization. Strange.

Comment: Does [this thread](http://markmail.org/thread/ugx2cku6bsj3g35v) help? If not, maybe add some details about your code, the User class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem and I guess I know how :-)

My resources were annotated like this:

```
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path(CONTEXT_ADDRESS)
public class UserResource
{
}
```

My client used the reverse order:

```
WebResource wr = ...
User user = wr.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(new GenericType<User>(){});
```

I don't know what initially caused the problem but I completely removed JSON-support and now it works. Maybe it would have been sufficient to simply swith the order of JSON and XML in the client but I didn't try that.

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same issue, searching on stackoverflow, I found that adding jersery-json-1.x.jar into WEB-INF/lib like suggested by  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027097/how-to-produce-json-output-with-jersey-1-6-using-jaxb) will solve the issue.
Please give award to [Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213782/mikhail)!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem (worked fine running from eclipse or deployed as separate jars but not from executable jar) and found that [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323501) for creating executable jars using the maven dependency plugin and maven jar plugin works properly.  This is because it puts the dependencies in a separate lib directory and then includes that in the classpath in the manifest as opposed to merging them all together which can cause numerous issues.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue (http://goo.gl/Mk9sZ) . It got solved by changing maven dependency for jersey-multipart jar from 1.0.2 to 1.8 version (Used the same dependency in client side as well as provider side.

```
             <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
             </dependency>
```

You can find the complete code I used at http://goo.gl/Mk9sZ

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jersey Client 1 and to solve this problem, I created a generic json message body reader.

```
public class JSONMessageBodyReader<T> implements MessageBodyReader<T> {

@Override
public boolean isReadable(Class<?> arg0, Type arg1, Annotation[] arg2,
        MediaType arg3) {
    return true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public T readFrom(Class<T> clazz, Type type, Annotation[] arg2,
        MediaType arg3, MultivaluedMap<String, String> arg4,
        InputStream is) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

    byte[] bytes = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(bytes);
    String json = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.readValue(json, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(type));

    return (T) mapper.readValue(json, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(type));

}
```

}