# How to produce JSON output with Jersey 1.6 using JAXB

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, jax-rs

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Todo {
    private String s = "test";

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

}
```

and service:

```
@Path("/test")
public class Service {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public List<Todo> getAllGadgets() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Todo[] { new Todo() });
    }

}
```

my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

All this work if I set  MediaType.APPLICATION_XML for Produces annotation. But for JSON I get the following exception:

> SEVERE: Mapped exception to response:
>   500 (Internal Server Error)
>   javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException:
>   com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A
>   message body writer for Java class
>   java.util.Arrays$ArrayList, and Java
>   type java.util.List,
>   and MIME media type application/json
>   was not found

I use Jersey 1.6 and, according to the tutorial, JSON format should work with JAXB without any additional programming. What's wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I solved this. All I needed to do was to add jersey-json-1.6.jar library to the project (this is not required part of jersey)

Comment: Thanks for this. I kept searching for a much more complex cause.

Comment: This doesnt work for me.I still get SEVERE: A message body writer for Java type, class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found. This is while running a test that uses an InMemoryContainer, so I wonder if it has something to do with that.

Comment: I had to change jersey-server to 1.9, jersey-core 1.9 and jersey-json to 1.9 jars.

Comment: how to do it for application/xml

Comment: Using Maven - I had to add: <dependency <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId> <version>1.17</version> </dependency>

Answer (score 14):

Add the following param to the jersey servlet in web.xml file, this is required for the latest 1.x versions of jersey-servlet.

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: I had everything from the accepted answer, and am using jersey v1.13; this is what solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The other answers didn't work for me, but I finally got it to work with JSON.

I was using the jersey-bundle-1.17.jar (also tried with the asm-3.1.jar and jersey-json-1.17.jar added to classpath and still didn't work). I finally tried downloading the zip that includes 12 different jars.  Once I added all 12 jars to my classpath I finally got rid of the error and works great returning JSON.

I hope this helps somebody.

**Update:** 
Here is a link to the zip file that contains the 12 jar files: [jersey-archive-1.17.zip](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-archive/1.17.1/jersey-archive-1.17.1.zip)

**Another Update for Maven Users:**
Add the following to your pom.xml to get the 12 jars individually:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you provide name or link of that zip file containing 12 jar files?

Comment: Sure thing. I just added a link to the zip file.

Comment: it gives me: 400 - Bad Request

Comment: Haha, sorry... Google moved the file. I added another reference to one on a public Maven 2 repository, so you should be good now.

Comment: I think I'm in the same situation as you here.  Is there any way to get this working with maven dependencies?

Comment: @tieTYT I have added the dependencies individually so you can just drop them into your pom.xml file.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I don't know why there are so many different answers that "worked".  Jersey must have changed a lot of things between versions.

Comment: I created a new question for this that I'd like you to answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646747/how-to-produce-json-output-with-jersey-1-17-1-using-jaxb  This can help others.  I went through a lot of trial and error to get this working before I noticed your answer way at the bottom.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's the answers lower-down on the list that actually end-up working. I added my answer to your other question. I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 6):

I use Google App Engine and have struggled a lot with this also, if you use jersey-bundle-1.17.jar most of the stuff work until you add

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

you will get a lot of strange messages. This is because you miss some jackson jars.
If you go to [jersey homepage](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html) and download the zip and the bundle. Just drop the bundle and from the zip you need to add the 4 jackson jars in your classpath and you should get everything working without any error.

Adding jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar solve this error below

```
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
```

Adding jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar solve this warrning below

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/codehaus/jackson/xc/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector

I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: I use jackson-jaxrs 1.9.13 + cxf-bundle-jaxrs 2.7.11. The problem I encounter is that the first request always fail, and successive requests are all success. During debugging, I notice NoClassDefFoundError exception like yours. Adding jackson-xc-1.9.2 solve the problem. I think it's jackson dependency problem

Answer (score 0):

The message body writer exception listed by the OP will be raised if you don't annotate your POJO (or base POJO) with `@XmlRootElement`.

For example:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class BaseBean
{
    private Boolean success = Boolean.TRUE;
    private String message;

    /**
     * Empty constructor to satisfy requirements of JAXRS.
     */
    public BaseBean() {}

    /**
     * Returns a simple message to accompany the success/failure.
     * @return
     */
    public String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the message (if required).
     * @param message
     */
    public void setMessage(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a flag indicating whether a request for content was
     * successful.
     * @return
     */
    public Boolean getSuccess()
    {
        return success;
    }

    /**
     * Marks the success of a request for content.
     * @param success
     */
    public void setSuccess(Boolean success)
    {
        this.success = success;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kamran's answer worked for me, just to expand more on the xml:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServletContainer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```