# A message body writer for Java class not found

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am new to using JAX-RS and wrote a sample application that outputs a json object. but I am getting an exception. Here is my code:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/query/{artist_id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Data getMsg(@PathParam("artist_id") int artist_id,
                            @QueryParam("from") int from,
                            @QueryParam("to") int to) {
        Data d=new Data();
        d.setName("Mateen");
        d.setRoll(77);
        return d;

    }
```

}

My data is simply a POJO class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Data {
    private int roll;
    private String name;
    public int getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }
    public void setRoll(int roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I get an exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: 
    com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: 
    A message body writer for Java class com.abc.data.Data, 
    and Java type class com.abc.data.Data, 
    and MIME media type application/json was not found
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: [please check this post, you need to register the ability for Jersey to output JSON][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161466/how-do-i-use-the-jersey-json-pojo-support

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to produce JSON output with Jersey 1.6 using JAXB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027097/how-to-produce-json-output-with-jersey-1-6-using-jaxb)

Comment: Why you need to provide @XmlRootElement on the bean?

Answer (score 102):

I finally found my answer. I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

to my pom.xml file. Then I added

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

to my web.xml file, and everything works fine. No change was required to my code above.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. Also, found the same on official web-page of Jersey https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html (Sections 5.1+5.2 at least)

Comment: I would like to know how I can write similar lines in the Gradle-built, "build.gradle" file with same function as the pom.xml refered above? My project is built on Gradle.

Comment: Recommend using `<scope>runtime</scope>`, because the code isn't compiled against the `jersey-json` package - just used at runtime.

Comment: @user1730789 Issue exists even i added jersey-json-1.9.1.jar. i have opened jar and no class like com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature

Answer (score 16):

I added following jars and it worked for me

- jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
- jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
- jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar

Answer (score 14):

Just a small addition. In case if you do not use the web.xml descriptor file, you may enable the POJOMappingFeatire programatically as shown below

```
...
final ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.test.resources");
    final Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    config.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", true);
    rc.setPropertiesAndFeatures(config);
...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342218/getting-error-a-message-body-writer-for-java-class-java-util-arraylist-listjava ..can you solve this ??

Comment: Please indicate where exactly do I add the above lines of code?

Answer (score 5):

#### Maven User: You just need the following 2 dependencies.

```
<!-- For Jersey --> 
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
</dependency>

<!-- For JSON --> 
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>    
</dependency>
```

XML output is supported by default. So no dependency needed for it.

Comment: FYI, this is only valid for using `web.xml` configuration. If you want to use `Applitation/ResourceConfig` subclass for your configuration, then you need the `jersey-container-servlet` instead of the `core`. The former, has the `ServletContainerInitializer`, which initializes the Jersey servlet, without the need for web.xml. If you are in a 2.5 servlet container, then you will need the `web.xml` though. No way around it. But most people should be in a 3.x containers anyway

Answer (score 4):

Working with Jersey 1.8, I was getting the same error while creating a JSON object and hitting a REST API from client side.

If you are facing issue at server side then, make sure that you have correctly included jersey-json.jar in classpath and mapped correct init-param in web.xml as mentioned in other answers.

### For Client Side

As per [Jersey 1.8 documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html), the following snippet shows how to use the POJO JSON mapping feature on the client side:

```
 ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
 clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING,Boolean.TRUE);
 Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:
 A message body writer for Java type, class java.lang.String, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found

The problem was that the class
javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter was taken from

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Was colliding with the same class from:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: so what is your solution to resolve above issue?