# How to send and receive JSON data from a restful webservice using Jersey API

Tags: java, json, jersey

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @POST
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject sayPlainTextHello(@PathParam("id")JSONObject inputJsonObj) {

        String input = (String) inputJsonObj.get("input");
        String output="The input you sent is :"+input;
        JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
        outputJsonObj.put("output", output);

        return outputJsonObj;
    }
}
```

This is my webservice (I am using Jersey API). But I could not figure out a way to call this method from a java rest client to send and receive the json data. I tried the following way to write the client

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
JSONObject inputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
inputJsonObj.put("input", "Value");
System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(inputJsonObj).post(JSONObject.class,JSONObject.class));
```

But this shows the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.lang.Class, and MIME media type, application/octet-stream, was not found
```

Comment: please improve your question by adding java as a tag and including 'Jersey API' in the title.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your use of @PathParam is incorrect. It does not follow these requirements as documented in the javadoc [here](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html). I believe you just want to POST the JSON entity. You can fix this in your resource method to accept JSON entity.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

  @POST
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public JSONObject sayPlainTextHello(JSONObject inputJsonObj) throws Exception {

    String input = (String) inputJsonObj.get("input");
    String output = "The input you sent is :" + input;
    JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
    outputJsonObj.put("output", output);

    return outputJsonObj;
  }
}
```

And, your client code should look like this:

```
  ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
  Client client = Client.create(config);
  client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
  WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
  JSONObject inputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
  inputJsonObj.put("input", "Value");
  System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(JSONObject.class, inputJsonObj));
```

Comment: For future Developers/ readers, this answer gives expected output. But You should import correct `jar` files. In my case I had `org.json` files and others in `jersey`. So getting error.. After import `com.sun.jersey` from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json) runs fine...

Answer (score 3):

For me, parameter (JSONObject inputJsonObj) was not working. I am using jersey 2.* Hence I feel this is the

#### java(Jax-rs) and Angular way

I hope it's helpful to someone using JAVA Rest and AngularJS like me.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Map<String, String> methodName(String data) throws Exception {
    JSONObject recoData = new JSONObject(data);
    //Do whatever with json object
}
```

Client side I used AngularJS

```
factory.update = function () {
data = {user:'Shreedhar Bhat',address:[{houseNo:105},{city:'Bengaluru'}]};
        data= JSON.stringify(data);//Convert object to string
        var d = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'REST/webApp/update',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
            data:data
        })
        .success(function (response) {
            d.resolve(response);
        })
        .error(function (response) {
            d.reject(response);
        });

        return d.promise;
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

The above problem can be solved by adding the following dependencies in your project, as i was facing the same problem.For more detail answer to this solution please refer link [SEVERE:MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml type=class java.util.HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439386/jersey-a-message-body-writer-for-java-class-and-mime-mediatype-application-json/51454244#51454244)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>   


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The last dependency is used to accept the json in the post call using jersey rest and the above two is to get the json from the rest as a response.