# IOException: Internal Server Error when trying to consume rest service

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, ioexception

I want to create a restful web service in java using *jersey API* and consume it in android application. I got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600510/how-to-send-and-receive-json-data-from-a-restful-webservice-using-jersey-api) on SO but it talks about java client whereas I have android client.

My service looks like this:

```
@Path("/no")
public class CheckNumber {

@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public String getDetails(@PathParam("cNo") String cNo) {
    String CardNo="";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(cNo);
        CardNo=jsonObj.getString("CardNo");
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Do something
    return "someValue";
   }
}
```

Now comes the client side:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    String wsdl = "http://192.168.1.105:8080/restdemo/check/no/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new RequestTask().execute("1234567890");

    }

    class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
         String add = "{\"CardNo\":\"" + uri[0] + "\"}";
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(wsdl);
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            postMethod.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(add);
            postMethod.setEntity(entity);
            response = httpclient.execute(postMethod);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new                             ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    responseString = out.toString();
                } else {
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just starting with rest web services. I successfully created a sample rest service which consumes string and returns string and used this service in android app.

But when I try to pass json string using POST method. It's giving following errorin log:

```
java.io.IOException: Internal Server Error
at com.example.restclient.MainActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:85)
```

where *MainActivity.java:85* is `throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());` which implies that `statusLine.getStatusCode()` is not returning `HttpStatus.SC_OK`. Instead it's returning status code = **500**.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: First, try the server logs, get to the exception. Does the server fail reliably or intermittently? Have you reproduced the error with a non-android implementation (java/wget/curl)? Have you seen the HTTP data that is being transferred over the network? (tcpdump -Xs1600 on the server might help)

Comment: statusLine.getStatusCode() is not returning HttpStatus.SC_OK

Comment: tried with simple java client also. same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be good to see the server side log to understand better.

Try creating the entity with UTF8 and set the content-type in the string entity rather than in the postMethod

```
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(myJsonDocStr, HTTP.UTF_8);
stringEntity.setContentType("application/json");
```

Comment: I used `HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("some url")
    postMethod.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity("some String");
    postMethod.setEntity(entity);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, It works for me

```
Boolean NetworkLostFlag = false;    

HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

    int timeoutConnection = 10000;

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
            timeoutConnection);

    int timeoutSocket = 12000;

    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strUrl");
            try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(new BasicNameValuePair(arg1, val1), "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            try {
                // do something useful

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                byte[] b = new byte[4096];
                for (int n; (n = instream.read(b)) != -1;) {
                    buffer.append(new String(b, 0, n));
                }
                result = buffer.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                NetworkLostFlag = true;
                // TODO: handle exception
            } finally {
                instream.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {         
        NetworkLostFlag = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: but you are using `httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(new BasicNameValuePair(arg1, val1), "UTF-8"));` while I want to use json string.