# Grizzly fails on MediaType.Application_JSON

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I'm following tutorial from pluralsight.com on how to setup the grizzly server and create rest apis.
If my method @produces plane text = then everything works, but if i have api method to return me a json file instead i'm getting

```
  Pom.file >>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.plurasight</groupId>
    <artifactId>async-rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>async-rest</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support:
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.plurasight.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.7</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Java classes files :

```
 BookDao



public class BookDao {
    private HashMap<String, Book> books;

    BookDao() {
        books = new HashMap<String, Book>();

        Book book1 = new Book();
        book1.setId("1");
        book1.setAuthor("Gino");
        book1.setTitle("Gino's book1");
        book1.setAspn("1234");
        book1.setPublishedDate(new Date());


        Book book2 = new Book();
        book1.setId("2");
        book1.setAuthor("Gino2");
        book1.setTitle("Gino's book2");
        book1.setAspn("2234");
        book1.setPublishedDate(new Date());


        Book book3 = new Book();
        book1.setId("3");
        book1.setAuthor("Gino");
        book1.setTitle("Gino's book1");
        book1.setAspn("3234");
        book1.setPublishedDate(new Date());

        books.put(book1.getId(), book1);
        books.put(book2.getId(), book2);
        books.put(book3.getId(), book3);

    }

    List<Book> getBooks() {
        List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>(books.values());

        return list;
    }

}
```

BookResource:

```
@Path("/books")
public class BookResource {

    BookDao dao = new BookDao();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getBooks() {
        System.out.println("PRINTLINE FROM BOOKS API");
//        GenericEntity<List<Book>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Book>>( dao.getBooks() ){};
        GenericEntity<List<Book>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Book>>(dao.getBooks()) {
        };

        return Response.ok(entity).build();
    }

}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main {
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/";

    public static HttpServer startServer() {
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.plurasight");
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final HttpServer server = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

Response from wadl

```
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
<doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 2.7 2014-03-12 18:11:31"/>
<doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:hint="This is simplified WADL with user and core resources only. To get full WADL with extended resources use the query parameter detail. Link: http://localhost:8080/myapp/application.wadl?detail=true"/>
<grammars/>
<resources base="http://localhost:8080/myapp/">
<resource path="/books">
<method id="getBooks" name="GET">
<response>
<representation mediaType="application/json"/>
</response>
</method>
</resource>
<resource path="myresource">
<method id="getIt" name="GET">
<response>
<representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
</response>
</method>
</resource>
</resources>
</application>
```

Responce on /getBooks api

```
PRINTLINE FROM BOOKS API
Oct 31, 2014 11:11:58 AM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<com.plurasight.Book>.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList and MIME media type application/json was not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116444/severe-a-message-body-writer-for-java-class-java-util-arraylist-and-mime-media)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cássio Mazzochi Molin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426227/c%C3%A1ssio-mazzochi-molin)s comment is correct!

You need to use `GenericEntity`:

> Represents a response entity of a generic type T.
>   Normally type erasure removes generic type information such that a Response instance that contains, e.g., an entity of type `List<String>` appears to contain a raw `List<?>` at runtime.

Therefore you need to implement something like that:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getDrivers() {
    System.out.println("printline from drivers api");
    GenericEntity<List<Driver>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Driver>>( dao.getDrivers() ){};
    return Response.ok(entity).build();
}
```

---

**Edit** *(updated question)*

I don't see a problem except your dependencies. Please add `MessageBodyWriter/-Reader` support by adding the the correct dependencies.

Resources I use under construction (Tomcat 7) are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Have a nice day...

Comment: Zyexal, so i modified my @Get method to this.. but i'm still getting error. It is slightly different then the previous one because i used to reutrn hashMap and now i made my getDrivers method to return List object so now it says   >>>>   SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.Collection<advertisingApis.Driver>.                    It doesnt seem that GenericEntity did matter in my case. Please do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please update your question. Add modified code and exception stacktrace - if possible. It seems to be a dependencie problem now. Therefore pls add maven pom.xml / lib folder content to your question. Pls add Driver.class, too.

Comment: thank you sir. 
I thought i'm missing something so i re-created the project based on all the instructions/as in tutorial and they use Books and not drivers. I'll update all the classes along with maven pom file in a second. Highly Appreciate your response.

Comment: *Edited* Hope this helps, 'cause afaig there are no other problems than the deps in your project :(

Comment: Zyeaxal.. I'm a blind person i guess..
In my pom file that was created on by this maven project the dependency on json is commented out. 2 days trying different things... and no clue to check pom file. First i didnt get what you mean but thought i saw it somewhere.. Anyways, thanks again for helping me to solve it. Appreciate it big time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64080/discussion-between-zyexal-and-gino).