# Jersey rest server - Return list as json

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I'm experiencing a difference in the json structure of a returned list running the same code when running on Tomcat and Glassfish.

```
@XmlRootElement
public Class Person {
    private int personId;
    private String name;
}

@GET
@Path("/persons")
public Response getPersons()
{
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    persons.add(new Person(1, "John Smith"));
    persons.add(new Person(2, "Jane Smith"));

    GenericEntity<List<Person>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Person>>(Lists.newArrayList<persons)) {};
    Return Response.ok(entity).build();
}
```

If returned in json format on tomcat (I'm running Tomcat on local machine) the result will be:

```
[
    {
        "personId" : "1",
        "name" : "John Smith"
    },
    {
        "personId" : "2",
        "name" : "Jane Smith"
    }
]
```

And if returned in json format on Glassfish (running Glassfish on remote server) the result will be:

```
{
    "person" : 
    [
        {
            "personId" : "1",
            "name" : "John Smith"
        },
        {
            "personId" : "2",
            "name" : "Jane Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I control this format my self? I would prefer the array-format (as on Tomcat) if possible. Either way I want it to produce the same result.

Edit:

Dependencies: 
jersey-container-servlet (2.14), 
jersey-server (2.14), 
jersey-media-moxy (2.14), 
javax.servlet-api (3.0.1)

Version of Glassfish: 3.1.2.2 (build 5)

Edit 2:
It's a problem with Jersey 2.14 and Glassfish 3.x

I just installed Glassfish 3 and 4 and deployed the rest app to check the response. It resulted in different json structure when returning a list. The response from Glassfish 4 was identical to the result I got when running on Tomcat.

Comment: Have you tried to to build the `Response` directly from the `List` without using the `GenericEntity`?

Comment: I've tried that but that doesn't work: SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.

Comment: Please post your dependencies and which Glassfish you are working with.

Comment: And what's the point of using List.newArrayList? Seems unnecessary

Comment: Yes, thats true. But that's not relevant to this problem thought, doesn't change the result.

Comment: When ever I see a problem related to this, I automatically think jettison, which as I've found in many cases is the culprit. Glassfish 3 uses jettison for its JAXB to JSON. That Glassfish's Jersey, which is very older 1.somethingLow, is loaded always, for its admin console. I believe that may have been the problem. Glad you got it sorted out :-)

Comment: The below link could help you figure it out [A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList…and MIME media type text/xml was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41429076/8228918)

Answer (score 1):

Try add the response mediatype annotation and try with the List not GenericEntity like this:

```
 @GET
 @Path("/persons")
 @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
 public Response getPersons()
 {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    persons.add(new Person(1, "John Smith"));
    persons.add(new Person(2, "Jane Smith"));

 Return Response.ok(persons).build();
 }
```

Comment: I've got the @Produces annotion on the class containing getPersons, like this: @Produces( { "application/json;qs=1", "application/xml;qs=.5" } ) So it's not that. Also returning the List results in error: SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.

Comment: Try then to return a List<Person> object. `public List<Person> getPersons() {` and to return just `return persons;` And you may also need an non-argument constructor on your Person Class for JAXB if you dont have it already.

Comment: Then I won't be able to return another object in case something goes wrong. I return a Message object containing a error message if something goes wrong.

Comment: Maybe this will help [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116444/severe-a-message-body-writer-for-java-class-java-util-arraylist-and-mime-media)

BTW. You can always throw exceptions if something goes wrong. Check [these](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException.html#NotFoundException(javax.ws.rs.core.Response)) all that extends WebApplicationException.

Comment: Ok, I think I will try to go for a solution where I return List<Person> and create my own exception extended from WebApplicationException to return a Message object

Comment: Didn't eliminate my original problem with difference in json structure though. Might be a problem with Glassfish 3.x and Jersey 2.x

Comment: One option is instead of using Jersey in-build functionality to create json string we can you [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to create json string and return String as response, by doing this I hope we can control over json conversion rather than playing with in-build jersey logic.