# Media type unsupported in REST client in java

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services

I am trying to call the rest client in java, here is the sample code

```
 private String getData (Map<String, String> inputList){
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:7080/xyz/rest/json/post");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> m : inputList.entrySet()){
            j.put(m.getKey(), m.getValue());
        }
        String input = j.toString();
        System.out.println("input:" + input);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new 
        OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        writer.write(input);
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }
    return output;      
}
```

This is the rest client program

```
@Path("/json")
public class RestClientExample{
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response restClientData(Map<String, String > mapList) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
Map<String,Map> map = new HashMap();
//Here get the map values based on the input received
return Response.status(201).entity(new Gson().toJson(map)).build();
}
```

This is the following error,

```
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class java.util.Map, and Java type 
java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>, and MIME media type 
application/json was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:

com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader

SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing 
to the HTTP container
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 415
```

Went through the following link  https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/

Kindly help me. If you have a working sample program, kindly share it. 
Thanks in advance.!!!

Comment: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22852881/5456789)

Comment: Thank you :) It was helpful.