# Is my webservice application really need to be convert to a dynamic web project to be able to deploy it with a .war file (with tomcat)

Tags: java, maven, web-services, jar, war

How can I we deploy a web service in Java by building a JAR or a WAR?

This part of my application is a REST web services with Jersey, Maven and  Eclipse (part of a N-tier  achitecture: Client-> Made with a game engine named Godot ,WebServices REST and a MySQL database).

I recently converted it to a web dynamic project but i was wondering if my webservice application really needed to be converted to a dynamic web project to be able to deploy it (with Tomcat)?

I use the HttpServer class to create a server.
Everything works fine when I work locally, but how can I make it work when I deploy it if I don't convert it to a dynamic web project?   This means with a JAR file when I build it. Do I need to combine both  WebressourceLaucher i create with HttpServer and  the dynamic web project (see below)?

This is how I was taught to do it:

My WebressourceLaucher class:

https://gyazo.com/e70f0c122b3ed76b7b669a36aa7bd0be

Here the structure of the project:
https://gyazo.com/8586b375113bad19753fe5526479cc44

Here my pom.xml to have more details about the project

https://sharemycode.fr/870

Comment: You don't need to convert it to a dynamic web project, as long as you produce a `WAR` with the [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/). It just informs Eclipse of the nature of your project and gives some additional tools/features for working in Eclipse. If you build an executable JAR, you have to start it per command line.

Comment: If you just need an installer, you could have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67907952/2135838

Comment: Thank you for your answer i choose to build an executable JAR  the webservice is lauching but it seems that when i build eclipse does not include hibernate.cfg.xml in the jar file. i get this :
juin 10, 2021 11:33:04 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
GRAVE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] any idea

Comment: Well, if you start your application in Eclipse, Eclipse builds the classpath for you and includes all the maven dependencies etc. To build an executable jar with maven you have to do a bit more than just create a jar. Please work through [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven).

Comment: Thank you again you are very helpful i choose Apache Maven Assembly Plugin solution i dont know if it's related but i get this error :

Comment: PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
GRAVE: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
i try to find solutions i check if i had good dependencies like jersey-json  but nothing change

Comment: Search for the error message. For instance it could be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20122256/2135838), but it could be any of the other solutions.