# How to convert jar file installer to Linux, Windows, MacOS supportable file?

Tags: java, linux, windows, spring-boot, maven

I have an executable jar file and how do I convert it into an installer file which should support to Windows(.exe), Linux(.rpm/.deb), macOS environments? Are there any native tools to do that? or any maven plugins?

Comment: Have you looked at the new tooling available in Java 16?

Comment: You can use something like [install4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html), which can be invoked per [maven plugin](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/cli/maven.html). An alternative would be [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page), also available with [maven-plugin](https://github.com/DigitalMediaServer/nsis-maven-plugin)